# P5 moving object around circle failed to destroy old objects

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to make a bubble circle around the circle. Unfortunately, the boundaries of 'old' bubbles remain displayed and despite the code is simple I can't figure out what's wrong.

```js
let radius = 150,
    angle = 0,
    speed = 0.01,
    centerX = 300,
    centerY = 300;

class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.col = color(255, 100, 76);
        this.diameter = 46;
    }
    display() {
        stroke(255);
        fill(this.col);
        this.x = centerX + radius * cos(angle);
        this.y = centerY + radius * sin(angle);
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);
        angle = angle + speed;
    }
};

var bubbles = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var x = 300;
        var y = 300;
        bubbles.push(new Bubble(x, y));
    };
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(300,300,300);
}

function draw() {
    // background(0);
    bubbles[0].display();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

If you try to run this you can see that the boundaries of old bubbles remain visible. It seems that the old bubble that is created is not destroyed when a new one (along the circular line) is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you try to run this you can see that the boundaries of old bubbles remain visible. It seems that the old bubble that is created is not destroyed when a new one (along the circular line) is shown.

No. The display is never cleared. It is just an new bubble with the color `color(255, 100, 76)` and the  white border (`stroke(255)`) drawn on top of the drawing of the previous frame.

Just clear the canvas with a white color before drawing and draw the black circular line in `draw`:

```js
function draw() {
    // clear canvas with white color
    background(255);

    // draw black circle
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    ellipse(300,300,300);

    // draw the one and only existing Bubble
    bubbles[0].display();
}
```

Note [`stroke()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/stroke) sets the color of the outline and [`noFill()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noFill) causes that the following shapes are not filled.

See the example:

```js
let radius = 150,
    angle = 0,
    speed = 0.01,
    centerX = 300,
    centerY = 300;

class Bubble {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.col = color(255, 100, 76);
        this.diameter = 46;
    }
    display() {
        stroke(255);
        fill(this.col);
        this.x = centerX + radius * cos(angle);
        this.y = centerY + radius * sin(angle);
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);
        angle = angle + speed;
    }
};

var bubbles = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var x = 300;
        var y = 300;
        bubbles.push(new Bubble(x, y));
    };
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    ellipse(300,300,300);
    bubbles[0].display();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```